# Vaadin application not allowing table row selection

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am using Vaadin 7, and have a table on which I've called the following:

```
    table.setSelectable(true);
    table.setMultiSelect(true);
    table.setImmediate(true);
    table.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_COMPACT);
    table.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_NO_HORIZONTAL_LINES);
    table.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
    table.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
    table.setPageLength(0);         // no scrolling for table alone.
```

I also call addValueChangeListener and pass in an anonymous listener to do special things with row selection.

My problem is that the table isn't allowing row selection. I've run Fiddler (an http monitoring tool); it shows ajax messages being sent when I click on a radio button on the page, but not when I click on a row in the table.

I have a breakpoint on the first line of the listener; it is not getting called.

Occasionally if I click on the table enough times, the breakpoint will get hit; I can't make that happen consistently. Mostly when I click on the table, the first row will get an outline around it, and nothing else happens regardless of how many times, or where, I click on the table.

Can anyone tell me possible reasons why the table would act like it was not selectable?

Comment: Just tried this with Vaadin 7.7.3 and it works flawlessly. Can you please provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Have you perhaps enabled serverpush? (In some rare/strange cases it sometimes conflicts with selections)